# ethzasl_icp_mapper doesn't publish data

Tags: navigation, kinect, icp, ethzasl-icp-mapping, bumblebee

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to use the "ethzasl_icp_mapping" package with a kinect.I roslaunch : "sensor.launch", "tracker.launch" and "tracker_viewer-groovy.launch" the topic "/point_map" is being published but there is no data in it. This has been verified with 'rostopic echo /point_map' and also on Rviz

rqt_graph shows that the "/mapper" node subscribes to "/stereo_camera/points2","/tf" and publishes "/point_map", "/icp_odom" and "/icp_error_odom".

How can i make this package work ?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63160/ethzasl_icp_mapper-doesn%27t-publish-data/) by [INSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4565/insa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2013-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you launching "sensor.launch", "tracker.launch" and "tracker_viewer-groovy.launch" in three different terminals? You need to run only "tracker_viewer-groovy.launch". By launching all three files, I get the same error which you mentioned. /mapper must subscribe to "/depth_registered/points".

---

Originally posted by [zahid](https://answers.ros.org/users/4557/zahid/) with karma: 81 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1